# Add files to an iso image and auto run a script post installation

Tags: script, iso-image, redhat-enterprise-linux

I want to add my `.tar` files in the `.iso` image of redhat cd and untar the same at desired location using some script. Can anyone tell

1. how do I add the files in the ISO image?
2. where to place the script?
3. how to link the script so that it is executed after the installation completes (redhat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to mount the ISO file on your HD and open it in an ISO editor (or so is my preference there may be other options) for example Daemon tools has an ISO editor and Vertual drives wich will help in troubleshooting and testing.

I can't help you with the other stuff I'm afraid.

Comment: thanx... hope i ll get the answer for the other stuff too...

Answer (score 1):

You can add files in iso by copying required files in directory where all files of iso copied, and then make iso out of that using command
 `mkisofs -r -o /tmp/iso_name.iso /dir_which_contain_all_files`

you can check by mounting iso file it conatin all files or not
using mount -o loop iso_name.iso /mnt

You can add calls of required script in kickstart file.

Ashitosh

Comment: can u pls tell where to place the script and how to call it in the kickstart file?.